# How can I pass Rawquery in ContentProvider?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

How can I pass the `rawQuery` using `ContentProvider` from one application to another application? Example: `select max(date) from tblename`

Example: Query Main Activity:

```
private Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://ubra.c.apps.pro/Details");
cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, "datePDate DESC");
```

In `ContentProvider`:

```
static UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static String PRO_NAME = "ubra.c.apps.pro";
Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PRO_NAME
        + "/Details");

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3,
        String arg4) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) 
    {
    case 1:         
        CPcursor = DBConnection.query("Details",  arg1, arg2, arg3,arg2, arg2, arg4);
        break;
```

How do I use `rawQuery` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution for the question.

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3,String arg4) 
{
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) 
    {
    case 1:         
       CPcursor =  DBConnection.rawQuery("Enter your SQL query Here"')", null);
        break;
}
}
```